# Extending a unitary operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ are two separable Hilbert spaces and that $X\subset \mathcal{H}_1$ is a dense subspace (i.e. $\overline{X}=\mathcal{H}_1$). If $\operatorname{W}:X \to \mathcal{H}_2$ is a linear surjective operator such that 
$$
\langle \operatorname{W}x, \operatorname{W}y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_2} = \langle x, y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1} \ \forall \ x,y\in \mathcal{H},
$$
then of course $\operatorname{W}$ is a [unitary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator). Now since $\overline{X}=\mathcal{H}_1$ we can extend $\operatorname{W}$ to the whole space $\mathcal{H}_1$, I do understand this last part, however the proof that I am reading also asserts that $\operatorname{W}:\mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_2$ is also a unitary operator and hence $\operatorname{W}^*\operatorname{W}=\operatorname{W}\operatorname{W}^*=\operatorname{I}$. I have trouble understanding that last part since we first had that $\operatorname{W}(X)=\mathcal{H}_2$, so how can we have that $\operatorname{W}^*:\mathcal{H}_2 \to \mathcal{H}_1$ is the inverse of $\operatorname{W}$?

All this comes from a proof of the spectral theorem on diagonalization of normal operators, and the argument is from *Carlos S. Kubrusly: Spectral Theory of Operators on Hilbert Spaces*. I am adding here a screen shot **(p. 72)** from the actual part proof where the operator $\operatorname{W}$ is extended, maybe there is something that I am missing. Any kind of help or insight will be very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: No, $W(X)$ is not $H_2$ (unless $X=H_1$. If $X$ is dense but not equal to $H_1$ then $X$ is not complete; since $W$ is an isometry $W(X)$ cannot be complete.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich that's it ! I knew I was missing something. However, when the proof says that $W$ is surjective then what exactly does that mean? Only that $W$ maps $X$ onto $W(X)$? Because for $W$ to be unitary I actually need it to be surjective

Comment: Not sure of what all the notation means, but it looks like the way it's stated in the proof is not quite right. _Note_ I know nothing about unbounded operators, etc, so I could be totally wrong here.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes something is fishy. However I think I have a correct proof that $W$ is indeed a surjective operator, hence as you said, this will mean that $X=H_1$, and in the proof's notation this means that a (at most countable) sum of $L^2(\Omega_j)$ spaces, with the $\Omega_j$ pairwise disjoint, is a complete space. I think that makes sense and fixes the proof. Nonetheless I will double check mi arguments. And I almost forget to thank you, your comments were very helpfull.